# Doxygen with CMake and CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, doxygen, clion

I want to use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) for documentation in my `CLion` project.

My project structure looks like this:

```
project root
|- ...
|- doc/
|- src/
|- ...
```

I want the documentation of the files in the `src/` folder to be placed inside `doc/`.

How do I have to configure `CMakeLists.txt` to achieve this?

I was searching and trying for a while but I couldn't find any good and **up-to-date** solution.

I found some references but I was not able to get any solution out of these.

- [CMake](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-February/012796.html)
- [tty1.net](https://tty1.net/blog/2014/cmake-doxygen_en.html)
- [Tip of the day: CMake and doxygen](https://majewsky.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/tip-of-the-day-cmake-and-doxygen/)

Comment: perhaps this [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/brunocodutra/metal/blob/master/doc/CMakeLists.txt) might be of some help. Be sure to also check [Doxyfile.in](https://github.com/brunocodutra/metal/blob/master/doc/Doxyfile.in).

Comment: As brunocodutra had mentioned: Let Doxyfile.in to control where the doxygen result stores, then use CMake to control when and how the doc is generated during the build.